# void type not allowed here when trying to loop through a HashSet?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and am trying to loop through a HashSet that has been created by using an enhanced for loop within my main method. I am getting the error "void" type not allowed here" and am not quite sure how to resolve this. I'm sure it may seem like a simple mistake to most people n here but I am very much a beginner so some help as to what this error means and how to resolve it would be much appreciated. Here is the code:

**Main class**

```
package lab5;
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        WordGroup firstWordGroup = new WordGroup("You-can-discover-more-about-a-person-in-an-hour-of-plau-tban-in-a-year-of-conversation");
        WordGroup secondWordGroup = new WordGroup ("When-you-play-play-hard-when-you-work-dont-play-at-all");

        System.out.println("*****First Array list*****");
        String[] firstWordArray =  firstWordGroup.getWordArray();
           for( String word : firstWordArray) { 
              System.out.println(word);
        }
        System.out.println("*****Second Array list*****");
        String[] secondWordArray =  secondWordGroup.getWordArray();
           for( String word : secondWordArray) { 
              System.out.println(word); 
        }
        secondWordGroup.getWordSet(secondWordGroup);
        firstWordGroup.getWordSet(firstWordGroup);

         for (WordGroup pp : secondWordGroup.getWordSet(secondWordGroup)) {
             System.out.println(pp);
        }
    }
}
```

**WordGroup class**

```
package lab5;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class WordGroup {

    String word;

    //Creates constructor which stores a string value in variable "word" and converts this into lower case using the lower case method.
    public WordGroup(String aString) {
        this.word = aString.toLowerCase();
    }
    public String[] getWordArray() {
        String[] wordArray = word.split("-");
        return wordArray;
    }


    public void getWordSet(WordGroup secondWordGroup) {

     HashSet<String> newHashSet = new HashSet<>();

    for (String word : secondWordGroup.getWordArray())
        newHashSet.add(word);

    for (String word : this.getWordArray())
        newHashSet.add(word);
    System.out.println(newHashSet);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Formatting your code and adding an indicator of where the error occurs would help.

Comment: When asking questions you need to put yourself in our shoes.  If you don't provide enough information, such as which statement is giving you the error, why should we spend time digging through your code to see if we can guess? Please, please visit the [help] and especially read [ask] before posting again.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public void getWordSet(WordGroup secondWordGroup) {
```

return the `Set<String>` you are building, like

```
public Set<String> getWordSet(WordGroup secondWordGroup) {
```

**and** add

```
return newHashSet;
```

to the end. Then, to iterate it with your `for-each` loop, it will be `String` so you will need

```
for (String pp : secondWordGroup.getWordSet(secondWordGroup)) {
    System.out.println(pp);
}
```